# How javascripts indexOfKey works

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array object like this

```
 var x =  [{"_id":null,"count":7},{"_id":false,"count":362},     {"_id":true,"count":926}]
```

How to take index of _id = false;  object

tried this `x.indexOfKey(false, "_id")` but returns -1 
and this works fine `x.indexOfKey(true, "_id")`

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: what is you trying to do?

Comment: nothing is wrong with this code. Just see if the console shows some error or not?

Comment: There is no such method `Array#indexOfKey` there is [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: There is no `indexOfKey` method on arrays in JavaScript. It must be something that you've added to the prototype either with a library or in another way.

Comment: I want index of the object where "_id" is false

Comment: look this :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700756.aspx

Comment: I would probably use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: oh we have a prototype where it return -1 if false thanks  @vid

Comment: @Xotic750 – May be.. But it has got poor support... With [`Polyfill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill), it could be used...

Comment: No problem with support for me as it is shimmable for non-ES6 environments. :) https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var array =  [{"_id":null,"count":7},{"_id":false,"count":362},{"_id":true,"count":926}];
var idx = -1;
array.filter(function(val, key) {
    if (val['_id'] === false) {
        idx = key;
     }
 });
```

Now the idx will have the index value of that particular object which is having key **_id** as **false** in above array.

```
console.log(idx); // 1
```

If we want multiple indexes of same key value then we can go with array

```
var array2 = [{"_id":null,"count":7},{"_id":false,"count":362},{"_id":true,"count":926}, {"_id":false,"count":462}];
var idxs = [];
array2.filter(function(val, key) {
   if (val['_id'] === false) {
        idxs.push(key);
    }
 });
```

This will track and push all the **idexes** of object into **idxs** array whose is having _id as false in above array2

```
console.log(idxs);   // [1,3]
```

Here is the working live example : https://jsbin.com/nukitam/2/edit?js,console

Hope this helps ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard `array.findIndex` API.

**See:**
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

```js
var x =  [{"_id":null,"count":7},{"_id":false,"count":362}, {"_id":true,"count":926}];
console.log("Index of _id==false is: " + x.findIndex((element) => { return element._id == false; }));
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the index from an array of objects using a property you can use this:

```js
var x = [{
  "_id": null,
  "count": 7
}, {
  "_id": false,
  "count": 362
}, {
  "_id": true,
  "count": 926
}]
var index = x.map(function(e) {
  return e._id;
}).indexOf(true);

console.log(index);
```

map the property into an array and then use `indexOf` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf